# i can't overwrite a function of qwidget created by quiloader

Tags: python, pyside2

i am trying to block the wheel events of a widget i don't understand why it works in the second code but it not works in the first code
please someone explain to me why in the second code for overload the wheelEvent function it works but does not works but in the first example
exactly in the first code i can move the QSlider with the wheel of the mouse and in the second code i cant do it what is the difference  why i can overload the wheelEvent in the second code but not in the first code

this does not works(the QSlider is allowed to move with the wheel of mouse)

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QDoubleSpinBox, QSlider
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(sf):
        super().__init__()
        loader = QUiLoader()
        form = loader.load('untitled.ui', sf)
        sf.f = form
        sf.ly_main = form.findChild(QVBoxLayout, 'verticalLayout')
        sf.sl_1 = form.findChild(QSlider, 'horizontalSlider')
        sf.setLayout(sf.ly_main)
        
        sf.sl_1.wheelEvent = lambda e : None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

this works(the QSlider is not allowed to move with the wheel of mouse)

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QDoubleSpinBox, QSlider
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(sf):
        super().__init__()
        sf.ly_main = QVBoxLayout()
        sf.sl_1 = QSlider()
        sf.ly_main.addWidget(sf.sl_1)
        sf.setLayout(sf.ly_main)
        
        sf.sl_1.wheelEvent = lambda e : None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

here is untitled.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>371</width>
     <height>271</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QDoubleSpinBox" name="doubleSpinBox"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QSlider" name="horizontalSlider">
      <property name="mouseTracking">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="focusPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::ClickFocus</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I can't do this".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok thanks i will do it